# Salesforce Send Email UI not displaying

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

The UI to send emails from Salesforce (including Subject, Body, etc.) is not displaying:
[image: Tab to send email from the Activity]

This Activity section is visible on the right of a Contact Record.
On the Related List "Activity History", the button "Email" is showing the same empty UI.

I am logged as a System Admin, I have all the permissions to access the object  EmailMessage;

The UI displays as expected when using Saleforce Classic:
[image]

Any idea of why the send Email UI is not displaying the normal set of fields (Subject, Body, To, etc.) with Lightning Experience?

Comment: I am discarding this issue/solution: "Chrome Cookie setting: Block third-party cookies need to be in a disabled mode" because I have just verified this option in disabled in my chrome browser: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384148&type=1

Comment: I have tested with another browser (Firefox Developer) and am getting the same issue: the UI is not displaying its content (as in the above screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the issue was that the Layout of the Global Action Email (API Name=SendEmail) did NOT contain any field.

After dragging-dropping the fields into the Global Action Layout, the functionality started working smoothly without the "error on parameter record: ava://sfdc.uisdk.connect.api.output.RecordRepresentation "

This resolves this issue.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it in same org, same user? You may have org-wide email ban (Setup -> Deliverability -> No access) or on profile are you sure you have "send email" selected?

Have you viewed same object in classic and lightning? maybe what you viewed in lightning doesn't have "allow activities" ticked in object's definition.

It sounds like it's "just" the email composer rich text area because the send button  is there. And couple more (but not all) buttons, interesting.

I'd expect 6 buttons: attach, merge field, template, preview, popup, discard

[image]

Any errors in Javascript console when you view this menu in lightning? (depends on browser, Windows users typically F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J, Mac users... command+option+J I think)

Comment: Question: Is it in same org, same user? --> Answer: Yes;

Comment: Q: You may have org-wide email ban (Setup -> Deliverability -> No access) --> Ans: nop, Setup>Deliverability>Access Level = 'All email';

Comment: Q: ... or on profile are you sure you have "send email" selected? --> A: Yes;

Comment: Q: Have you viewed same object in classic and lightning? maybe what you viewed in lightning doesn't have "allow activities" ticked in object's definition. --> A: Yes, the object I am looking at is the standard Contact object. I think "Track Activities" activities cannot be disabled on a standard object.

Comment: Q: It sounds like it's "just" the email composer rich text area because the send button is there. --> Yes, the button is already appearing, it is the just the Rich Text composer that is not displaying.

Comment: Now, I am spotting a new error when clicking the button 'Send' --> Error on parameter record: java://sfdc.uisdk.connect.api.output.RecordRepresentation

Comment: How does it look on another device or in sf mobile app? Maybe adblock or antivirus block some javascript from running? Do you have any custom lightning components dropped on same page, maybe some CSS rules are "leaking" and hiding the editor

Comment: I colleague of mine, with a different laptop, different User (System Admin) has visited the same Contact Record and she is getting the same error when clicking the button "Send" --> Error on parameter record: java://sfdc.uisdk.connect.api.output.RecordRepresentation

Comment: Are you sure it's standard send email component? https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003fSTQAY suggests it's custom coded one.  Is there a class similar to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm in the org? Are you able to send emails in Lightning in another org, say your own developer edition. "Connect" in that "link" makes me think of Chater, is Chatter enabled in this org?